# Fetch data from second database frequently while connection to first database is always available

Tags: php, mysql

I m working on old existing project which uses `mysql` function for database operation. The existing system connects to the database, say `cdcol`. The connection to this database is available through site wise. 
Now I want to fetch data from another database say `crawlerdb`, assign fetched data to an array and close connection to this database. The connection to second database is inside a function say `GetAccess`, and each time the extra data needed, the function is called, data fetched and connection closed to the second database.
All I want is connection to first database should be available every time.

The problem I m facing is. If i don't close connection to second database. Then mysql query used after calling the function `GetAccess`, still search items from second database, because the connection to second database is active. If I close the connection to second database, still the query doesnot work. Following code explains my situation.

```
<?php
//$conn1 is permanent connection that is used sitewise.
$conn1=mysql_connect("localhost","root","",true) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("cdcol",$conn1) or die(mysql_error());
echo "1. Current Database = ".mysql_current_db();//prints cdcol
echo "<Br> Function Returned Value = ".GetAccess();

echo "<Br>2. Current Database = ".mysql_current_db(); //In GetAccess function, which is called above if mysql_close($conn2) is used, the mysql_current_db() returns empty value.

//A FUNCTION TO GET EXTRA DATA FROM SECOND DATABASE
function GetAccess(){
    $conn2=mysql_connect("localhost","root","",true) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("crawlerdb",$conn2) or die(mysql_error());
    $test=mysql_query("select * from tbllensinfo",$conn2); //here i have used $conn2 as link identifier
    $var= mysql_num_rows($test);
    mysql_close($conn2);
    return $var;
}

//FUNCTION TO IDENTIFY WHICH DATABASE IS CURRENTLY BEING USED
function mysql_current_db() {
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT DATABASE()") or die(mysql_error());
    return mysql_result($r,0);
}
$res=mysql_query("select * from cds"); //here link identifier $conn1 is not used, i cant change this code because there are several 100s codes, so not possible to change in all of them. Everything will work if $conn1 is used here though
echo "<br>".mysql_num_rows($res);


?>
```

**NOTE:**
The two database are hosted on same server, but database users are different, one of which have no access to other database.

So in short What I need is I need to fetch data from second database frequently while connection to first database is always available.

Any help will highly be appreciable, thanks !

Thanks
Sharmila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql functions, such as `mysql_query`, all have an optional `resource` parameter identifying the database connection to use.  If you omit this second parameter, the functions use the *most recently opened* connection. That is, they use the connection resulting from the *most recent* call to `mysql_connect`. It's considered the most recent result even if you have closed it already.

(Global variable! Let's party like it's 1999!)

If you're going to use more than one connection with mysql calls in your program, you must specify the `resource` parameter in *all* `mysql_*` calls in your program.

Please consider switching to PDO or mysqli.  The PHP people have been trying to get rid of this `mysql` API for years, partly because of this problem, and mostly because it has serious insecurities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I m aware of the fact. In newer project I always use PDO or mysqli. This one is very old project and a bigger one too, so I can't make a bigger changes to the code at the moment. Which means there is no solution to my problem?

Comment: Oh. (Smacking my forehead.) What a mess, eh?  Could you use PDO or mysqli to handle the queries to your alternative database, and leave `mysql_` for the existing code? I don't know if it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Just tried with PDO, and it seem to work fine, and hence this solves my question. Thanks a lot!